# Java program doesn't work on vista 32 bits

Tags: java, windows, windows-vista

so i have made a program in java and i tested it on windows 7 64 bits, it work pretty good but when i tried to run in a windows vista 32 bits, most of the program methods doesn't work, for exemple, a simple piece of code like this

```
propriedades.store(new FileOutputStream("c:\\Sms beta 1.0\\config.properties"), null);
```

don't work on vista, the program run and the frames are displayed but saving files and connecting some devices from COM ports to the computer doesn't work and i can't figure out why...
It's because any protection of vista or there may be some methods that can be only used by 64 bits system?
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Java code is machine independent but sometimes might need changes due to OS constraints.

Comment: In particular, where you can create files is highly configuration and OS dependent.

Comment: "doesn't work" is *never* enough information. It's like going to the doctor and saying "I'm ill" without providing any symptoms.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. (copied from flag dialog)

Comment: I don't get any errors... i got a virtual machine with windows vista 32 bits and xp 32 bits (didn't work on xp also) i did a sys output of the error and i got this:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Sms beta 1.0\config.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileNotFoundException` implies one of two things:

1. The folder `C:\Sms beta 1.0` doesn't exist.
2. The folder does exist, but your program doesn't have permission to write to it and/or the file in it. Change the permissions of the folder (right-click it and click 'Properties' -> 'Security') to allow read & write access by the user that the program runs as, or to change the owner of the folder. Or, run the program as a different user account that has the necessary permissions.

I suspect it's a permissions issue, since you also mentioned a problem accessing COM ports. Perhaps you are running the program as an administrator on your Windows 7 machine, but as a regular user on Vista.

Comment: I manage to make it create the files in windows vista, i got the full access to everything, now i just have to see if i can get access to the COM Ports... ty for everything